# When do absolute values $| \cdot|$ retain inequalities? What about for norms?

Tags: absolute-value

Can I substitute stuff inside $| \cdot|$ and retain inequalities?

Example: want to make

$$
\left|\frac{m}{n} - 1 \right|
< \epsilon,
\quad \epsilon > 0; \quad n,m \in \mathbb{N}$$

Could I say:

Take
$$
n > \frac{m}{\epsilon+1}
$$
so that
$$
\left|\frac{m}{n} - 1 \right|
< \left| \frac{m}{\frac{m}{\epsilon+1}} - 1 \right|
= |\epsilon + 1 - 1|
= \epsilon.
$$

---

Now for this simple case this seems to work, since for a fixed and positive constant $1$ it's safely known that the distance of a larger positive quantity from that will lead to larger distance.

However, I don't think the $| \cdot |$ would always allow this kind of "positive real line" modifications?

Any background to this "property" or non-property of $|\cdot|$ or why not norms as well? What would one test for? That the operation is such that it's explainable either by homogeneity or triangle eq. (or possible C-S)?

In general, when do absolute values and norms retain inequalities?

Comment: Yes, $|x|<1$ implies $x<1$. No, $x<1$ does not imply $|x|<1$. Yes, $|x|<1$ and $x$ nonnegative imply $x<1$. This is all there is to it...

Comment: $0 < 1$ but $|0-2| > |1-2|$